# Google Maps Marker On Load Handler?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

All,
Very simply - is there an onload handler / event for when all markers have loaded?

Eg we have 26 markers being loaded, and this is loading well before the markers:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
    // do something only the first time the map is loaded
});
```

Also fyi this does not work:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(marker,'load',function(){
// onload stuff
});
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Team,

Ok so I think I answered my own question - Not as elegant as I'd hoped but this works:

In our createMarker function, I added a 'checkloaded()' bit to the end, which checks if locations.length = markers.length:

```
function createMarker(add,lat,lng,marker_label) {
        var contentString = '<div contentEditable="true">'+marker_label+'</div>';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
           map: map,
           draggable: true,
           label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length]
                 });


        // open marker on load
        google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click');

        bounds.extend(marker.position);

        //Add marker to the array.
        markers.push(marker);

        checkloaded();

       }
```

And then:

```
function checkloaded(){
  if(locations.length == markers.length){
    // do onload stuff here
  }
}
```

If there is a proper way to do that, let me know and thank you all